# Is there a way to detect if a user has a black or white iphone?

Tags: ios, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Differentiate between black and white iPhones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466707/differentiate-between-black-and-white-iphones)

I wanted to fine tune some visuals tro look better with a white iphone, but havent had any luck on google.

Answer (score -2):

Do not put images of an iPhone into your software. It's grounds for rejection for copyright/trademark issues.

We had some cartoonish iPhone images - not even that realistic - and were told to remove them. Seriously.