# Best way to get type of iOS device in the codee

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've been doing this, which works just fine, to see if my universal app is running on iPad or iPhone/iPad:

`BOOL isIpad=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width<500?NO:YES`

Any reason I should not based my test on the UIScreen bounds, or is there a better method?

Comment: iPhone 5?  (AKA - not a future proof test)

Comment: You can even deciphre the color of the device: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466707/differentiate-between-black-and-white-iphones

Comment: But the iPhone 4 is 640 pixels wide but it still passes this test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing for the screen size is a very fragile test. Luckily, Apple already tells you what kind of device you're running on.

For that, use the `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` macro:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    // Got an iPad.
} else {
    // == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone
    // Got an iPhone or iPod Touch.
}
```

Comment: Any update for how to do an iPhone 5 check?  Or do we now need to use the value of [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height?  Perhaps this should be a new question.  But the answer to my question impacts this answer now, so..

Comment: Yes, this is a new question, but so far the answer is indeed to check the height of the mainScreen (at least that's the solution that was quoted in the Apple developer forum over and over again, there's no other reliable and future-proof way to check this).