# How to detect the colour of an iPhone 5c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7

After iPhone 5c announcement, i'm curious if anybody knows an API how to get an iPhone 5c colour? I'm sure everyone will find it convenient loading a corresponding UI colour scheme to the device colour.

I'm thinking about wrapping it in something like the UIDevice category, which will return a UIColor.

**Update:**
@ColinE and @Ortwin Gentz
 has indicated the availability of private UIDevice instance method calls for it.

**Please note, that in case of iPhone 5c, what you are really looking for is deviceEnclosureColor, as deviceColor will always return #3b3b3c, as it is a front colour.**

method signature:

```
-(id)_deviceInfoForKey:(struct __CFString { }*)arg1
```

UIDevice category for it:

```
@interface UIDevice (deviceColour)

- (id)_deviceInfoForKey:(struct __CFString { }*)arg1;
- (NSString*)deviceColourString_UntilAppleMakesItPublic;
- (NSString*)deviceEnclosureColour_UntilAppleMakesItPublic;


@end

@implementation UIDevice (deviceColour)

- (NSString*)deviceColourString_UntilAppleMakesItPublic
{
    return [self _deviceInfoForKey:@"DeviceColor"];
}

- (NSString*)deviceEnclosureColour_UntilAppleMakesItPublic
{
    return [self _deviceInfoForKey:@"DeviceEnclosureColor"];
}


@end
```

Comment: Clever idea!!! You may get some hints from discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463212/detecting-color-of-iphone-ipod-touch

Comment: I don't think there is a public API available to to that.

Comment: Ok got it, but It seems quite logical to integrate an UI colour scheme with a device colour, so maybe they will provide something, don't u think?

Comment: Yes, iOS 7 is still under NDA, and will be until the official release date, 18 September 2013. Are you a registered, paying developer? If so, ask on the Apple Developer forums.

Comment: I am, and I already did. Here's the link: https://devforums.apple.com/message/887633#887633

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it deals with technology which is still under NDA.

Comment: Questions covered by a third party NDA are not offtopic in StackOverflow. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94488/162235

Comment: If I where you, I would have 5 different UI themes ready and let the user chose. As a user, it's very annoying when a device/software stubbornly outsmarts you and doesn't let you set things up the way you would prefer. Some people might want to mix device/UI colors, e.g. just like the Apple cases.

Comment: yes, I do have different UI colour schemes, which user can choose from settings view, but for me the default scheme should be the same as the device colour. This all is just to avoid asking user on the first launch - which UI colour scheme do you want to choose.

Comment: Ah, but the real question is what is the API for *changing* the color?

Comment: Hurden, the device color is always #3b3b3c in case of the iPhone 5c, so I think your update is a bit misleading. Check my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I updated it, just never tested it on 5c, still have to wait 1 month till we can get it here.

Comment: Is this ok to use? Just want to be sure my app won't be rejected if it's not.

Comment: It is more likely it will get rejected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a private API to retrieve both the `DeviceColor` and the `DeviceEnclosureColor`. In case of the iPhone 5c, the interesting part is the enclosure color (the device color = front color is always #3b3b3c).

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"deviceInfoForKey:");
if (![device respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"_deviceInfoForKey:");
}
if ([device respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    NSLog(@"DeviceColor: %@ DeviceEnclosureColor: %@", [device performSelector:selector withObject:@"DeviceColor"], [device performSelector:selector withObject:@"DeviceEnclosureColor"]);
}
```

I've blogged about this and provide a sample app:

http://www.futuretap.com/blog/device-colors/

**Warning: As mentioned, this is a private API. Don't use this in App Store builds.**

Answer (score 13):

The device colour (used to?) be encoded in the serial number of the device. I don't have a device to test on with them not officially released yet, but I imagine the solution will be similar to this:

> Typical format of the iPhone SN is as follows: AABCCDDDEEF
>
> AA = Factory and Machine ID
>  B = Year of Manufacturing (9 is
>   2009/2019, 0 is 2010/2020, 1 is 2011 and so on)
>  CC = Production
>   Week (01 is week 1 of B, 11 is week 11 of B and so on)
>  DDD =
>   Unique Identifier
>  EE = Color (A4=black)
>  F = size (S=16GB,
>   T=32GB)

<sup><sup><sup>[[Source]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466717/916299)</sup></sup></sup>

There is more information on old techniques [here](http://www.pressbyte.com/640/decode-iphone-hardware-information-serial-number/)

---

I would like to point out however, that I expect there isn't a supported method of getting the serial number. Assuming you'd only like to know this information so that you can customise your UI, I'd just put in a user option or ask them to select the colour of their device on first startup (or some other early point in the app-user life)

Answer (score 3):

A number of people on Twitter have [cited the following method](https://twitter.com/stroughtonsmith/status/379679342865166336):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] _deviceInfoForKey:@"DeviceColor"]
```

Although I have not confirmed it myself.

Comment: Note that the _ indicates this is a private method.

Comment: So, How do we use to this method ? :/

Comment: @Amaud, the answer is that you don't, at least not in an app you want to submit to the app store.

Comment: @Arnaud, the answer to how to use private API method is to create a category on UIDevice, and add the following private signature into interface section -(id)_deviceInfoForKey:(struct __CFString { }*)arg1;

This will return an NSString with a colour name. If u ran it on simulator it will return @"unknown".
(method signature is taken from complete listing of API available - https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers)

Comment: The device color is always #3b3b3c in case of the iPhone 5c so it doesn't help much. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you...

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([device.systemVersion hasPrefix:@"7"] ? @"_deviceInfoForKey:" : @"deviceInfoForKey:");
    if ([device respondsToSelector:selector]) {
        NSLog(@"DeviceColor: %@ DeviceEnclosureColor: %@",
              [device performSelector:selector withObject:@"DeviceColor"],
              [device performSelector:selector withObject:@"DeviceEnclosureColor"]);
    }
```

Ref: [Detecting Color of iPhone/iPad/iPod touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463212/detecting-color-of-iphone-ipod-touch/19334257#19334257)