# How to get current device's picture (as shown in iTunes)?

Tags: ios

Is there any way to obtain a picture of current iOS device? I mean the picture of white iPhone 5 if i'm running code on white iPhone 5, picture of black iPad mini, when running on black iPad mini and so on. Apple shows this picture in iTunes for current device:
[image]

and in the Xcode Devices, and I think this picture is included somewhere and hopefully can be accessed in code to be shown to user (like "your current device picture").

Comment: You can get the device code and match it to your custom image, but you most certainly won't find a public API to get the said image..

Comment: The images of the devies them self are in the iTunes app, there are called `DeviceIcons.rsrc` and `DeviceImages.rsrc`. Thus you will not be able to get them easily.

Answer (score 0):

Apple currently does not allow to get device color, at least from Public API.

You can take a look [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769758/how-to-detect-the-colour-of-an-iphone-5c) which uses Apple Private API, but never use this for App Store submission. If you still decide to use this API, All you need to do, is to create phone images for all the device colors and for all device models [This is the link how to get device model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-how-to-get-device-make-and-model). Then, all left to do for you is to write bunch of if statements and that's it.