# Detecting iPhone/iPad color in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uidevice

I would like my app to show a black background interface when it is run on a black fronted device, and a white interface when the device front is not black. What I found so far is:

- an official UIDevice.current API, but I can not find an information on device color there, unless UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor (i.e. UUID) has it encoded?
- a hinted solution for objective-C ([How to detect the colour of an iPhone 5c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769758/how-to-detect-the-colour-of-an-iphone-5c)), however I didn't managed to run it under Swift, and probably an app with this solution will not pass through an App Store revision.

Is it possible to get device front color info?

Comment: You would need to use private API like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769758/how-to-detect-the-colour-of-an-iphone-5c

Comment: You need to learn the mindset of Apple in general they want a good user-experience and Apps that work across multiple platforms is their goal. Something like this would go against their sales and statistics and just because someone wants to use your app with dark background , he would need to buy the Black iPhone. I don't see this being an official API ever (my opinion only).